# How to install oracle 11g XE and use the data files of another instance (like Postgres)?

Tags: oracle11g, installation

I installed Oracle 11g XE in Windows 7 x64, then  Windows 8.1 (install new OS, not perform an upgrade of the previously Windows 7 x64 installation).
Can be possible to install Oracle 11g XE over the existing directory to use the database that was created with Windows 7 like Postgres do when the Data Directory exists?

Comment: I zipped the old Oracle directory, installed Oracle over the old Oracle directory, al changes lost, then stoped Oracle services, renamed the new directory and unzipped the old directory, then started Oracle again and all data is usable again.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use another DB's datafiles in place of Oracle's. You will have to develop a solution that will handle the exporting and importing of data from the Postgres DB into the Oracle DB.

Comment: I dont mean copy the data files of Postgres to Oracle, just to mention in example that when installing Postgres, you can specify the data directory, and you can use an existing one.

Comment: @FernandoSoto Ah I think I understand now. You would like to reuse data files from a previous oracle installation, correct?

Comment: Correct. I followed the steps described in the question coment and worked for me. Also un in [dba.se](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/81689/how-to-install-oracle-11g-xe-and-use-the-data-files-of-another-instance-like-po/81690) is a more elaborated answer.

Comment: Great news. Glad you figured it out.